# check if row exists before inserting in athena table

Tags: insert, amazon-athena

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy4oq.jpg)

[Result i am getting when same row is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okoPp.jpg)

I want to check if the same row exists before inserting into athena to avoid any duplicate rows in table abc.

Is it possible to use "check if exists" in athena table. The below code is being used to add data in table abc.

```
insert into table abc 
with tmp as(
select 
  date,
  price1,
  price2 
from 
  table2
)
select 
   *
from 
   tmp
where 
   price1 > 100
;
```

Comment: This is too much of pseudo code. Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. Also, how do you identify a duplicate?

Comment: I have edited the post and result screenshots i have atteched.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely check if rows already exist - you could work with `where not exists`:

> NOT EXISTS is satisfied if no rows are returned by the subquery

```sql
with tmp as(
select 
  date,
  price1,
  price2 
from 
  table2
)
select 
   *
from 
   tmp
where price1 > 100
and not exists (select 1 from abc where abc.date = tmp.date)
```

However, keep in mind that Athena can't update data that is once written.